# DSL Jenkins pass parameter to phaseJob

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

On Groovy DSL how can I use jenkins parameters in a phaseJob name.
 When trying to do

stringParam('jobName', 'bla', 'blabla')
...
phaseJob('$jobName')

jobName is not replaced with the value I entered in Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes. As you can read [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

> Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals, *apart from single and triple single quoted* strings.

You need to use double quotes in order to make `"string ${interpolation}"` work:

```
phaseJob("$jobName")
```